# Basic question about index notation

Tags: calculus, index-notation

I was trying to make a basic calculation. Suppose that $\partial_{\nu}A^{\nu}=f$ where $f$ is a scalar field. How can i find the expression for $A^{\nu}$. I mean, there is a way to express $A^{\nu}$ as the integral of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as soon as you go to more than $1$ dimension there is not enough information to invert a contraction like this. Indeed, if all you know is that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_i}=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n),
$$
then if you find one $A$ satisfying this equation then you can add any $B$ satisfying
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial B}{\partial x_i}=0\qquad(\star)
$$
and thereby obtain another $A'=A+B$ satisfying the same equation.

For example, any function of the form
$$
a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_{n}x_n
$$
where $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=0$ will satisfy $(\star)$. (And many, many, others...)

Comment: Thank you. 

I understand that $A$ this is not determined unlikely.

But there is a way to find one $A$? 

I have a problem where i have to find $A$, when $f$ is the Ricci Scalar.But based in your answer is looks like is not possible in a simple way.

Comment: You say that i need more information to invert a  contraction like this, what is the other information that i need?

Comment: Usually it will be a partial differential equation that $A$ satisfies, and the contraction will be a sort of boundary condition. In the case of the Ricci tensor you seem to be interested in, the pde may be these for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations